# Nginx статика CSS

Tags: nginx

Сам index.html nginx отдает, однако, подключенные стили в html `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">`  в Response
передает в text/plain, соответственно ошибка MIME type.
Бьюсь уже полдня.
Памаги-и-и-те!!!! -))

Nginx.conf

```
events {}

http {
      include /etc/nginx/mime.type;         ###этот файл реально есть в папке
      sendfile.on;
      default_type application/octet-stream;  ###хз че делает -))

      server {
              server_name 192.168.111.111
              location / {
                          root /root/path/to/index/static;
                          index  index.html;
                          }
              }
}
```

Comment: `sendfile.on` - ошибка. что говорит `nginx -t`?

Comment: все ок у него). Я закомментил его уже. Не знаю куда копать уже.... Почему-то mime.type не работает никак.

Comment: так быть не может. этот конфиг даст, как минимум, `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "sendfile.on" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:`

Comment: syntax is ok.    test is successful.   Пардон, там не точка, а пробел

Comment: и файл `/etc/nginx/mime.type` прям вот есть? именно `type`, вместо `types`?

Comment: Можете еще помочь?)) Теперь пытаюсь отдать статику nginx-ом, а все остальное проксировать на Node. Но если делаю блок location с proxy, и не запускаю сервер Node, то Nginx не отдает статику (ошибка 502)

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html